# undefined is not an object (evaluating the FBSDKAccessTokenInterface.getCurrentAccessToken)

Tags: android, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I am having trouble with my ability to get the AccessToken in the fbsdk in React Native.

I am calling the core as suggested by Facebook:

```
const FBSDKCore = require('react-native-fbsdkcore');
const {
  FBSDKAccessToken,
} = FBSDKCore;
```

And in one scenario I try to write the token in the log as suggested by a similair question stated here on SO.

```
<View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', padding: 50, marginTop: 250}}>
    <View> 
      <LoginButton
        publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
        onLoginFinished={
          (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
              alert("login has error: " + result.error);
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
              alert("login is cancelled.");
            } else {
              FBSDKAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken((token)=> {
                    console.log(token);
                  });                          
              Actions.Navigator()
            }
          }
        }
        onLogoutFinished={() => {
          alert("logout.")}}/>
    </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

This gives me the redscreen "undefined is not an object (evaluating the FBSDKAccessTokenInterface.getCurrentAccessToken)

Trying to pull off something similair in other parts of the app, of course defining the const FBSDKAccessToken first, then calling the userID (which should be a part of the FBSDKCore) as:

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color:colors.General.navtext}}>{FBSDKAccessToken.userID}</Text>
```

Yields nothing, where I believed it to return the userID of the logged in user. Also, if I try to write out the accesstoken in that same place as:

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color:colors.General.navtext}}>{FBSDKAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()}</Text>
```

I get the same red screen as before.

I tried to look in to the linking of libraries, but that even caused further problem.

Hence, from this, I am pretty stranded and I would really appreciate some feedback on what has gone wrong.

Comment: Are sure sure you have linked library to your project? Sounds like FBSDK package is not properly added to your project and causing undefined error.

Comment: Hey @MikeGrabowski thanks for trying to help me .. well i thought it's a linking problem also and it probably is but i don't know how to solve it .. i read the docs about linking and i used rnpm to link it and it says that it's linked .. but it probably ain't linked . i'm not using a mac btw , i have ubuntu .

Comment: FBSDK doesn't work that well with `rnpm` as far as I know. If you have Discord (app) installed, you can find me there and we can try to debug it :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with FBSDKCore. Fixed it by using react-native-fbsdk

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  AccessToken,
} = FBSDK;
```

Did you double-check these steps mentioned by facebook:

- Make sure that the Facebook SDK frameworks are installed in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK.
- Make sure that FBSDK[Core, Login, Share]Kit.framework show up in the Link Binary with Libraries section of your build target's Build Phases.
- Make sure that ~/Documents/FacebookSDK is in the Framework Search Path of your build target's Build Settings.

(https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment . i'll try it soon and get back to ya :D